# How to load data using nodejs and assign it to variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication

I'm newbie with nodejs. What I want to do is load users data, insert it to array and then assign it to variable.

If in PHP, I need to load data using my model.

I already have one method in nodejs to retrieve all users data (I already create the API).

This is my API routes :

```
router.get('/', ctl.getAllUser);
```

ctl.getAllUser refers to this method :

```
getAllUser(req, res, next) {
    db.any('SELECT * FROM users')
    .then((data) => {
        if (data.length === 0) {
            throw abort(404, 'No user data yet', 'Empty user table');
        }

        return res.status(200).json({
            status: 'success',
            data,
            message: 'Retrieved all users data',
      });
    })
    .catch(err => next(err));
},
```

usually I access it using :

```
http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users
```

But I don't know how to load it, and assign it to one variable.

This is the format that I want.

```
var users = [{  
    id: 1,
    name: "indra.gunawan",
    email: "indra.gunawan@gmail.com",
    password: "123456"
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "Jamie Christian",
    email: "j.christianm@gmail.com",
    password: "123456"
}];

module.exports = users;
```

Comment: Why do you need to assign it to a variable? What you've got looks like it works. What do you mean "load it manually"? Just call the function....?

Comment: how can i do that bro? can you give me an example? thankyou

Comment: Well, `getAllUser` looks like a handler for an Express route. Are you using Express? You would just call `getAllUser(req, res)` inside your route handler.

Comment: pls see my question agian bro. i explain it more clearly.

Comment: Sorry, that makes it even more confusing. Please try and explain clearly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Since your getAllUser() function returns a promise you need to subscribe it.

Something like this:

```
ctl.getAllUser().subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```